# reduce number of rows by cbinding data, also rename columns

Tags: r

I want to "partially" make the data.frame "wider"
Not really succeeding in doing so.

#### data looks like

```
 ID X1 X2 X3 X4
 1l  1  5  9 13
 1r  2  6 10 14
 2r  3  7 11 15
 2l  4  8 12 16
```

#### desired output

```
 ID X1_l X2_l X3_l X4_l X1_r X2_r X3_r X4_r
  1    1    5    9   13    2    6   10   14
  2    4    8   12   16    3    7   11   15
```

#### rep data

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("1l","1r","2r","2l"),matrix(1:16,ncol=4))
```

#### please note:

1. the order of `l` and `r` are not always the same. As shown in the example. So no cheating possible here. We could do a natural sort to solve that but let's don't do it. Possibly there is a single `r` or `l` number. So for e.g., there exists `18l` but NOT `18r`.

My try is to first split the data up by same numbers: Like so

```
split(x = df,f = sub("[lr]","",df$ID))
```

Any fast solutions for a problem like that?

#### Edit

@Arkun

Error Message:

```
    Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (7561, 7562), (7581, 7582), (7599, 7600), (7619, 7620), (7563, 7564), (7583, 7584), (7601, 7602), (7621, 7622), (7565, 7566), (7585, 7586), (7603, 7604), (7623, 7624), (7567, 7568), (7587, 7588), (7605, 7606), (7625, 7626), (7569, 7570), (7607, 7608), (7571, 7572), (7589, 7590), (7609, 7610), (7573, 7574), (7591, 7592), (7611, 7612), (7575, 7576), (7593, 7594), (7613, 7614), (7577, 7578), (7595, 7596), (7615, 7616), (7579, 7580), (7597, 7598), (7617, 7618), (6577, 6578), (6597, 6598), (6615, 6616), (6635, 6636), (6579, 6580), (6599, 6600), (6617, 6618), (6637, 6638), (6581, 6582), (6601, 6602), (6619, 6620), (6639, 6640), (6583, 6584), (6603, 6604), (6621, 6622), (6641, 6642), (6585, 6586), (6623, 6624), (6587, 6588), (6605, 6606), (6625, 6626), (6589, 6590), (6607, 6608), (6627, 6628), (6591, 6592), (6609, 6610), (6629, 6630), (6593, 6594), (6611, 6612), (6631, 6632), (6595, 6596), (6613, 6614), (6633, 6634), (7643, 7644), (7663, 7664), (7681, 76
In addition: Warning message:
Too many values at 66 locations: 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, ...
```

About the real data:

43 patients (1r,1l, ... 43r,43l)
About 112 Variables. First after ID is called `v2_1_prot` and last `v2_80_CK`

So i replaced the part of `x1:x4` with `v2_1_prot:v2_80_CK`. Am I doing something wrong here?

I checked my ID variable there are not duplicates so far.

```
all_pat_rbind2$ID %>% count %>% extract2("freq") %>% max # is equal to one
```

Comment: Looks like you may need a group_by operation after `unite` i.e. `%>% group_by(ID, key_v1) %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% ungroup() %>% spread(key_v1, val)`

Comment: trying that my 41 patient df `82x104` becomes a `12x1238` result

Comment: Perhaps change the group_by to include only ID.  Without a reproducible example, it is not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use methods from `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   separate(ID, into = c("ID", "v1"), sep="(?<=\\d)(?![0-9])") %>% 
   gather(key, val,  -one_of("ID", "v1"))  %>% 
   unite(key_v1, key, v1) %>% 
   spread(key_v1, val)
#  ID X1_l X1_r X2_l X2_r X3_l X3_r X4_l X4_r
#1  1    1    2    5    6    9   10   13   14
#2  2    4    3    8    7   12   11   16   15
```

Comment: nice solution, does need some tweaking for my real data: how can i replace x1:x4 with my first (after ID) variable and last variable. Is there a command for that?

Comment: on a smaller subset of my real data your above solution gets me the right result. There must be something that distorts it.

Comment: I think i know what the error is: when the ID go up to 10r it cuts the 10 into 1 | 0. It cuts after the first digit. I just need to figure out how to change the SEP accordingly.

Comment: @AndreElrico  Ohh okay, now i got the problem.  It should be `"(?<=\\d)(?![0-9])"`

Comment: changing gather to `gather(key, val, -one_of("ID", "v1"))` it becomes a very general solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
temp = gsub("\\D+", "", df$ID)
data.frame(ID = unique(temp), do.call(cbind, lapply(X = c("l", "r"),
    FUN = function(f) setNames(object = data.frame(sapply(X = names(df)[-1],
        FUN = function(cx) sapply(X = unique(temp),
            FUN = function(rx) df[df$ID == paste0(rx,f),cx]))),
        nm = paste(names(df)[-1], f, sep = "_")))))
#  ID X1_l X2_l X3_l X4_l X1_r X2_r X3_r X4_r
#1  1    1    5    9   13    2    6   10   14
#2  2    4    8   12   16    3    7   11   15
```

Comment: This solutions seems to work: my `82x104` becomes a `41x207`

Comment: I will check the data by eye now